# Split strings in DataFrame and keep only certain parts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, apply

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
x = ['3.13.1.7-2.1', '3.21.1.8-2.2', '4.20.1.6-2.1', '4.8.1.2-2.0', '5.23.1.10-2.2']
df = pd.DataFrame(data = x, columns = ['id'])

    id
0   3.13.1.7-2.1
1   3.21.1.8-2.2
2   4.20.1.6-2.1
3   4.8.1.2-2.0
4   5.23.1.10-2.2
```

I need to split each id string on the periods, and then I need to know when the second part is 13 and the third part is 1. Ideally, I would have one additional column that is a boolean value (in the above example, index 0 would be TRUE and all others would be FALSE). But I could live with multiple additional columns, where one or more contain individual string parts, and one is for said boolean value.

I first tried to just split the string into parts:

```
df['id_split'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: str(x).split('.'))
```

This worked, however if I try to isolate only the second part of the string like this...

```
df['id_split'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: str(x).split('.')[1])
```

...I get an error that the list index is out of range.

Yet, if I check any individual index in the DataFrame like this...

```
df['id_split'][0][1]
```

...this works, producing only the second item in the list of strings.

I guess I'm not familiar enough with what the .apply() method is doing to know why it won't accept list indices. But anyway, I'd like to know how I can isolate just the second and third parts of each string, check their values, and output a boolean based on those values, in a scalable manner (the actual dataset is millions of rows). Thanks!

Comment: `df.id.str.split(".",expand=True)` will provide you multiple columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it directly, like below:

```
df['new'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: str(x).split('.')[1]=='13' and str(x).split('.')[2]=='1')

>>> print(df)
              id    new
0   3.13.1.7-2.1   True
1   3.21.1.8-2.2  False
2   4.20.1.6-2.1  False
3    4.8.1.2-2.0  False
4  5.23.1.10-2.2  False
```

Comment: Weird... this works on my sample dataset, but I still get the "list index is out of range" error on my actual dataset. I'll accept this answer anyway, since it does work and I'm not sure what the critical difference is between the two dfs. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect there are some cells with less than 2 occurences of '.' which will lead the str(x).split('.')[2] to this error

Answer (score 1):

Let's use `str.split` to get the parts, then you can compare:

```
parts = df['id'].str.split('\.', expand=True)

(parts[[1,2]] == ['13','1']).all(1)
```

Output:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks, I wound up using this method in my actual code, because as mentioned in a comment above, I couldn't get the first answer to work on my actual dataset even though it is a valid method on this test dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
df['flag'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: True if x.split('.')[1] == '13' and x.split('.')[2]=='1' else False)
```

Output

```
            id   flag
0   3.13.1.7-2.1   True
1   3.21.1.8-2.2  False
2   4.20.1.6-2.1  False
3    4.8.1.2-2.0  False
4  5.23.1.10-2.2  False
```